# Can I to import custom field's metadata into a custom object in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I used the Salesforce DevTools extension to export all custom fields of a custom object in Salesforce,
I logged into another Salesforce account. After creating the custom object, I wanted to import all the custom fields exported above into this object.

I've searched but still can't find a free tool to do this import.
Does anyone know please help me.
Thanks!